# Decoding name of file attachment doesnt work with properties

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I read this documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html

so I add some properties to mimeMessage:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.mime.decodefilename", true);

    Session mailConnection = Session.getInstance(props, null);

    source = new FileInputStream(emlFile);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailConnection, source);
```

now I am expectaing that method `bodyPart.getFileName()` return correct name of file. But with this configuration it still doesn work and I need to call mimeUtils: `MimeUtility.decodeText` - what I dont want. I also try:

```
        props.put("mail.mime.decodefilename", "true");
```

but with no success. So what I am doing wrong ?

UPDATE:

after debuging I had this sollution:

this works

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();        
    props.put("mail.mime.decodefilename", "true");
```

this doesnt work:

```
    Properties props = new Properites();
    props.put("mail.mime.decodefilename", "true");
```

so if filename is decoding depends on system property too. Does anyone know which properties ? I dont have pattion to try all system properties and solve which one it is

Comment: For encoding you need to set `"mail.mime.encodefilename"`.

Comment: sorry mislick I mean decode whole time

Comment: You should probably ask this as a new question. I believe the problem you originally had was resolved with my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MimeMessage.getFileName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getFileName%28%29)

> If the mail.mime.encodefilename System property is set to true, the
>   MimeUtility.decodeText method will be used to decode the filename.

---

Now when one looks at the implementation, this is how the `MimeUtility.decodeText` comes into picture during the invocation of `getFileName`:

```
if (decodeFileName && filename != null) {
    try {
    filename = MimeUtility.decodeText(filename);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throw new MessagingException("Can't decode filename", ex);
    }
}
```

Where `decodeFileName` is initialized like this:

```
s = System.getProperty("mail.mime.decodefilename");
// default to false
decodeFileName = s != null && !s.equalsIgnoreCase("false");
```

---

The `javadoc` seems to be conflicting with the implementation.

So, try setting `mail.mime.decodefilename` instead of `mail.mime.encodefilename`, probably using [`System.setProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: See my update. Try setting `mail.mime.decodefilename` instead.

Comment: thx a lot I try all possiblity and this helps me:         props.put("mail.mime.decodefilename", "true");

Comment: The javadocs for the [javax.mail.internet package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html) make this clear; scroll down to the description of the properties.  The [MimeBodyPart.getFileName method](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#getFileName()) also clearly states that it's a **System** property.